# How to check if an attribute exists in an object's dynamic struct

Tags: go

I'm confused about how to check if an attribute exists in an object's dynamic struct. I.e. if we have the following structs:

```
type Animal struct {
    Name string
    Origin string
}

type Bird struct {
    Animal
    Speed float32
    CanFly bool
}

type Bear struct {
    Animal
    Lazy bool
}
```

And now I have a function using `Animal` as a parameter:

```
func checkAminalSpeed (a Animal){

    // if the struct of current animal doesn't have the Speed attribute
    // print ("I don't have a speed")
    
    //otherwise, return the speed of this animal
}
```

This function is trying to check the varible's runtime type to choose action.

I'd like to know in this case, how to write this `checkAminalSpeed` function? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go does [not support inheritance](https://golang.org/doc/faq#inheritance), but perhaps you'll find the following approach tolerable.

Use an `interface` to define the `Animal`'s behaviour:

```golang
type Animal interface {
    GetName() string
    GetOrigin() string
    GetSpeed() float32
}
```

Use a "base" type that will contain common fields and also implement the behaviour:

```golang
type AnimalBase struct {
    Name   string
    Origin string
}

func (a AnimalBase) GetName() string   { return a.Name }
func (a AnimalBase) GetOrigin() string { return a.Origin }
func (a AnimalBase) GetSpeed() float32 { return -1 }
```

Embed the "base" type and override any behaviour you need to:

```golang
type Bird struct {
    AnimalBase
    Speed  float32
    CanFly bool
}

func (b Bird) GetSpeed() float32 { return b.Speed }
```

And then...

```golang
func checkAminalSpeed(a Animal) {
    if speed := a.GetSpeed(); speed == -1 {
        fmt.Println("I don't have speed")
    } else {
        fmt.Println(speed)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/KIjfC7Rdyls

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was wondering about, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

mkopriva is right. Go does not support inheritance, you can use reflect and  interface{}  also

ps:  reflect cost more time  than interface

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Animal struct {
    Name string
    Origin string
}

type Bird struct {
    Animal
    Speed float32
    CanFly bool
}

type Bear struct {
    Animal
    Lazy bool
}

func checkAminalSpeed (a interface{}){
    v := reflect.ValueOf(a)
    if f, ok := v.Type().FieldByName("Speed"); ok{
        fmt.Printf("%v\n", f)
    }

}

func main() {
    checkAminalSpeed(Bird{})
    checkAminalSpeed(Bear{})
}
```